# How to reach a product from multiple set values - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 sets of:

```
A = [0, 10, 20]
B = [5, 10, 15]
C = [2, 5]
```

I am running the following list comprehension to see how Cartesian products can match a target value of 40.

```
from itertools import product

xx = [p for p in (product(A, B, C)) if sum(p) == 40]

print(list(xx))
```

Giving a result of

```
[(20, 15, 5)]
```

The above result is pulling 1 figure from each set to complete the target value. I want to pull 2 figures from A and B, and pull 1 figure from C for this result. How can I change my solution to get a result such as:

```
[(0, 20, 5, 10, 5]
```

Comment: What is the product function you are using? Also, you probably don't need to use list(xx) as it's already a list

Comment: Can you have duplicate values in `A`, `B` or `C`?

Comment: Yes, occasionally there will be duplicate values in A, B, or C @jpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One **brute-force** method is to use nested `for` loops. Here's a generator version:

```
from itertools import combinations, product

A = [0, 10, 20]
B = [5, 10, 15]
C = [2, 5]

def sum_to_val(A, B, C, k):
    for combs_a in combinations(A, 2):
        for combs_b in combinations(B, 2):
            for val_c in C:
                L = (*combs_a, *combs_b, val_c)
                if sum(L) == k:
                    yield L

res = list(sum_to_val(A, B, C, 40))

[(0, 10, 10, 15, 5), (0, 20, 5, 10, 5)]
```

Answer (score 3):

What about considering the cartesian product of `A x A x B x B x C`?

```
xx = [list(p) for p in product(A, A, B, B, C) if sum(p) == 40 and p[0] != p[1] and p[2] != p[3]]
print(xx)
```

This gives us

```
[[0, 10, 10, 15, 5], [0, 10, 15, 10, 5], [0, 20, 5, 10, 5], [0, 20, 10, 5, 5],
[10, 0, 10, 15, 5], [10, 0, 15, 10, 5], [20, 0, 5, 10, 5], [20, 0, 10, 5, 5]]
```

If you don't want to consider ordering for the 2 elements you pick from `A` and `B`, you could sort their "picks" and construct a `set` of the final result:

```
xx_unique = set([tuple(sorted(p[:2]) + sorted(p[2:4]) + p[4:]) for p in xx])
print(xx_unique)
# {(0, 10, 10, 15, 5), (0, 20, 5, 10, 5)}
```

**Note**: As @MadPhysicist pointed out, in case you have duplicates in your lists, you may want to consider the product of the indices first and then reconstruct your desired 5-tuples:

```
xxi = [p for p in product(range(len(A)), range(len(A)), range(len(B)), range(len(B)), range(len(C))) if p[0] != p[1] and p[2] != p[3]]

xx = [ [A[i], A[j], B[k], B[l], C[m]] for i, j, k, l, m in xxi if sum([A[i], A[j], B[k], B[l], C[m]]) == 40 ]
```

Comment: You may want to recast the product in terms of indices since `p[0] != p[1] and p[2] != p[3]` may not work correctly if the lists have duplicates. That being said, OP did say "sets".